# Blocked by "You can only post once every 40 minutes." after a failed post

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign

I attempted to post a question, but forgot to type in a title. After filling in a title, I was blocked by a 40 minute timer. Is this the intended behavior?

Since my attempt was blocked because of incompleteness (and so, it was not actually posted), would it be reasonable to expect to be able to post immediately after making the post complete?

---

I may not have characterized the bug properly. It seems a post to Literature will be blocked for 40 minutes after a post to Literature-Meta. Is this the intended behavior? Would it be reasonable to expect that each site would be on separate timers?

---

As a suggestion for an alternative way of doing things, perhaps a user could be limited to 36 posts per 24 hour period across both sites, without the delay between successive posts that are within the 36 post limit.

Comment: If you don't have any rep on the site you're trying to post to, you need to wait 40 minutes before asking another question on a site you have no rep on. Since Literature and Literature Meta are different sites, and you had no rep on either one of them, you got blocked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Is this the intended behavior?*

## Yes.

From [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/322265) on rate-limiting questions for new users, catalogued at [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900/278659) (both of the posts I just linked contain a LOT more detail on rate limiting and its rationale):

> The new-user ask limit is now one question every **40** minutes, *network-wide*. That means only 1 question every 40 minutes on Stack Overflow, but also means you'd need to wait 40 minutes after asking a question on, say, Woodworking to ask a related question on Crafting or Home Improvement.